# Rescaling an ODE

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

I have a Cauchy problem

$$ \left\{ \begin{array}{l} \dot{x} = f(x) \\ x(0) = x_0 \end{array} \right. $$

with $x = x(t)$. Suppose to have $y(t) = a x\left(\frac{t}{b}\right)$, where $a$ and $b$ are real constants.

I would like to write another Cauchy problem for the variable $y$:

$$ \left\{ \begin{array}{l} \dot{y} = g(y, a, b) \\ y(0) = y_0(x_0, a, b) \end{array} \right. $$

It is easy to show that $y(0) = y_0(x_0, a, b) = ax_0$. What can I say about $g(y, a, b)$?

Comment: $g(y,a,b)=bf(ax)?$ It should be but please check this assertion carefully. The best is to craft a quick explicit example and do a test.

Comment: Well, if I have $\dot{x} = \lambda x$ and $x(0) = 1$, then $x(t) = e^{\lambda t}$ and $y(t) = a e^{\frac{\lambda t}{b}}$. In this way, we have that $y(0) = a$ and $\dot{y} = \frac{\lambda x}{b} \neq ab\lambda x = bf(ax)$

Comment: My previous post maybe is wrong. However, I don't understand how can I manage $g(y,a,b)=bf(ax)$? The right-hand side does not show $y$...

Comment: I realized that, if $b=1$, then $g(y, a, b) = a f(\frac{y}{a})$, but I'm far from writing it for every $b$...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally I got it!!!

For a general ODE likes:

$$\frac{d}{dt}x(t) = f(x(t), t)$$

we have that:

$$\begin{array}{rl} 
\displaystyle\frac{d}{dt}y(t) & = \displaystyle\frac{d}{dt}a x\left(\frac{t}{b}\right) \Rightarrow \\
\displaystyle\frac{d}{dt}y(t) & = \displaystyle\frac{a}{b} f\left(x\left(\frac{t}{b}\right), \frac{t}{b}\right) = \frac{a}{b} f\left(\frac{y(t)}{a} , \frac{t}{b}\right) = g(y(t),t,a,b),
\end{array}$$

and

$$y(0) = y_0(x_0, a, b) = ax_0$$