# Renormalization to get $x'=e^{-x}$ instead of $x'=e^{-ax}, a>0$.

Tags: real-analysis

Sorry if this is a stupid question but how can I renormalize in order to get
$$
x'=e^{-x}
$$
from $x'=e^{-ax}$ where $a>0$?

Can I set $\tilde{x}=\frac{x}{a}$?

Comment: by $x'$, do you mean a real number or the derivative of a function?

Comment: Derivation of function

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't deal with real analysis regularly, so for my own sake I'll clarify the notations a little: let $x(t)$ be a real function such that $x'(t)=e^{-ax(t)}$, with $a>0$. Set $y(t):=ax\left(\frac ta\right)$. Then
$$y'(t)=\frac aax'\left(\frac ta\right)=e^{-ax\left(\frac ta\right)}=e^{-y(t)}.$$

Comment: I was thinking about time rescaling. Say, consider the equations (1) $x'=f(x)=e^{-ax}$ and (2) $x'=g(x)\cdot f(x)=e^{-x}=e^{-x}$ where $g(x)=e^{ax}e^{-x}$. Consider $B(t)=\int_0^t\frac{1}{g(x(s))}\, ds$ where $x$ is a solution of (1). By $\beta(t)$ denote the inverse of $B(t)$. Then $\tilde{x}(t):=x(\beta(t))$ solves (2). Is this what you did? - I am not sure how to compute $\beta(t)$ here.

Comment: No, that's not what I did. With your calculations, $\tilde x'(t)=\beta'(t)e^{-ax(\beta(t))}$. I don't see how you reconcile this expression with $e^{-\tilde x}=e^{-x(\beta(t))}$.

Comment: But am I right that my argument shows that (1) and (2) have the same solution curves (up to time rescaling)? Although if we do not know the expression for $\beta$ explicitly?

Comment: I think you are right about that. You can check out this post: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/329639/rescaling-an-ode. I think they found the differential equation that the rescaled function satisfies: if $x'(t)=f(x(t),t)$, then $y'(t)=\frac abf\left(\frac{x(t)}b,\frac tb\right)$, where $y(t)=ax(\frac tb)$.

Comment: Does this mean that in my notation $\beta(t)=\frac tb$ and  $g(x)=\frac ab$?

Comment: Yes $\hspace{0ex}$

Comment: But I do not see how to compute $g(x)$ and $\beta(x)$ without already knowing the form of y.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/107987/discussion-between-isaac-ren-and-john-doe).